# Transparent background for text by opacity

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, transparency, opacity

I'm a little new in wpf. I want to make transparent background for the text. I achieved it with the `AllowsTransparency = true; background = Colors.Transparent` but the animation was like chopping. I read here [Strange Choppy WPF Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313003/strange-choppy-wpf-animation)
that's common for the `AllowsTransparency` property, so I want to make it by opacity. I have XAML code:

```
 <Grid x:Name="Gridd">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Viewbox x:Name="MainWindow1">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="00:00:00" FontFamily="Digital-7 Mono" FontSize="50" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        </Viewbox>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </Grid>
```

I want to change opacity dynamically, each time I try to make background transparent by opacity, the text vanish  also. Any tips?

Comment: You need to create a static resource with Opacity property and bind it to transparent property through custom binding.

Comment: What does the static resource means? any example of binding to help me imagine it?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jitendra1987/using-staticresources-in-wpf/

Comment: Okay! Thanks, I found an solution but I'll consider yours which may be much better :) thanks

Comment: Please upvote the comments as they will help others quickly read the useful comments.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with `OpacityMask` which "choose" color to make transparent when `Opacity` on the window is set to 0. Now i can choose the same `Color` for the `OpacityMask` and `Background`. The background vanish and text is still visible

Comment: It's WRONG!! I didn't notice that i have still `allowtransparency = true`, opacity DOES NOT work without setting this property to `true`

Comment: It's good solution to make background transparent by `Opacity` and `OpacityMask` but it will result with black background if `AllowTransparency = false`